# Find indices of neighbors in masked region

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have this piece of code:

```
[I, J] = find(mask == 1);

for k = 1 : numel(I) 
    i = I(k);
    j = J(k); 

    neighbor_ind = [i, j - 1;
                    i, j + 1;
                    i - 1, j;
                    i + 1, j];
end
```

Now I would like to find all indices `s` such that `[I(s), J(s)]` is equal to one of the rows in `neighbor_ind`. The neighbor indices for which this is not possible should be ignored.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT: Here is a small example.**

Suppose we have the mask

```
0     0     0     0
0     1     1     0
0     1     1     0
0     0     0     0
```

(it does not have to be rectangular)

`[I, J] = find(mask == 1)` will give `I = [2, 3, 2, 3]` and `J = [2, 2, 3, 3]`.

Now lets set `i = 2, j = 2`.
There are two neighbors inside the mask, and two outside. I want to know where in `I, J` I need to go look to find these neighbors. In this example, the solution would be `I(3), J(3)` for the right neighbor, and `I(2), J(2)` for the bottom neighbor.

Comment: @beaker Yes i have the toolbox

Comment: Yes but sub2ind will give me the linear index in the hole image. But I have used the find function and I, J are a subset of indices.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to get. Can you give an example?

Comment: @beaker I posted an example how it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any ideas on how you'd do this that wouldn't involve searching through all of the indices.

Comment: @beaker Thank you for the help anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nchoosek` to generate indices of neighbors.

```
mask = [...
0     0     0     0
0     1     1     0
0     1     1     0
0     0     0     0];
[R , C] = find(mask==1);
n = numel(R);
idx_pix = (n:-1:1).';
idx_neighbors = nchoosek(1:n,n-1);
```

that results:

```
idx_pix =

   4
   3
   2
   1

idx_neighbors =

   1   2   3
   1   2   4
   1   3   4
   2   3   4
```

So in your example `(n == 4)` neighbors of 4th pixel are `[1 2 3]`
in the other words :

```
neighbors of `idx_pix(1)` are `idx_neighbors(1,:)` : 4 ->>  1 2 3
neighbors of `idx_pix(2)` are `idx_neighbors(2,:)` : 3 ->>  1 2 4
neighbors of `idx_pix(3)` are `idx_neighbors(3,:)` : 2 ->>  1 3 4
neighbors of `idx_pix(4)` are `idx_neighbors(4,:)` : 1 ->>  2 3 4
```

or
    neighbors of `R(idx_pix(1))` are `R(idx_neighbors(1,:))`

...
...
...

note: It is more efficient to use linear indices instead of rows and columns so you can use this signature: `IDX = find(mask==1);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have make your answer work in my code but I will accept your answer for now. Thanks a lot.